# Annotations No Longer Show After Package Update

Tags: python, opencv

I upgraded all my packages and somehow the annotations stopped showing when I play my video on OpenCV. How can I resolve this?

I have tried downgrading to

```
opencv_contrib_python-4.8.0.74.dist-info
opencv_python-4.7.0.72.dist-info
```

but annotations are still not showing up.

I also have the following code for the annotations:

```
cv2.rectangle(image, 
                          (coords[0], coords[1]+5), 
                          (coords[0]+len(body_language_class)*20, coords[1]-30), 
                          (245, 117, 16), -1)
            cv2.putText(image, body_language_class, coords, 
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
            
            # Get status box
            cv2.rectangle(image, (0,0), (250, 60), (245, 117, 16), -1)
            
            # Display Class
            cv2.putText(image, 'CLASS'
                        , (95,12), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.putText(image, body_language_class.split(' ')[0]
                        , (90,40), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
            
            # Display Probability
            cv2.putText(image, 'PROB'
                        , (15,12), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.putText(image, str(round(body_language_prob[np.argmax(body_language_prob)],2))
                        , (10,40), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
```

Comment: never install multiple opencv packages. -- [mre] required. what you've posted so far isn't a MRE in that it's neither standalone nor is it minimal.

Comment: Do you get any error messages?  Are your coordinate proper integers compatible with cv2.putText(). Have you checked the documentation for your new version to see if any changes in cv2.putText()?  What debugging have you done?

Comment: Sorry, it's my bad. I eventually found out my annotations weren't showing up because I had removed some of the features to feed into my model, but Mediapipe requires all landmarks to be included for the annotations to show up. 

TLDR: The issue isn't with the package, it's with my features.